# AngularJS: Inject custom service into module.config function not possible?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

i try to inject a custom service into the module config function, but i get an error that the service is undefined:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.config(function($httpProvider, CommonConfigService) {

    var baseUrl = CommonConfigService.getRESTUrl();

});
```

I use this within a couple of controllers without any problem.

Can someone hint me how to solve this?

Thanks and kind regards

Comment: is the service is injected in angular.module('myApp.services')

Answer (score 1):

You cannot inject services to a `config` acording to [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) ,

> Configuration blocks - get executed during the provider registrations
>   and configuration phase. Only providers and constants can be injected
>   into configuration blocks. This is to prevent accidental instantiation
>   of services before they have been fully configured.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if service was created as provide. Instead of:

```
app.factory('MyFactory', function(){});
```

Use

```
app.provider('MyFactory', function(){});
```

Then you can inject it like so:

```
app.config(function($httpProvider, MyFactoryProvider) {
    var baseUrl = MyFactoryProvider.getRESTUrl();
});
```